# How to use Split function in spark sql with delemter |@|?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

My column is having data as,

```
col
---
abc|@|pqr|@|xyz
aaa|@|sss|@|sdf
```

It is delemeted by |@| (pipe ,@ , pipe).

How to split this with spark sql.

I am trying `spark.sql("select split(col,'|@|')").show()` but it is not giving me proper result.
I tried escaping \ but still no luck.

Can anyone knows what is going on here..

Note: I need solution for spark  sql only.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem statement properly or not but to split a string by its delimiter is fairly simple and can be done in a variety of ways.

One of the methods is to use SUBSTRING_INDEX -

```
val data = Seq(("abc|@|pqr|@|xyz"),("aaa|@|sss|@|sdf")).toDF("col1")
data.createOrReplaceTempView("testSplit")
```

followed by -

```
%sql
select *,substring_index(col1,'|@|',1) as value1, substring_index(col1,'|@|',2) as value2, substring_index(col1,'|@|',3) as value3 from testSplit
```

Result -

[image: Spark SQL Query Result]

**OR** - [Split Function Documentation](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-split-dataframe-column-into-multiple-columns/)

```
%sql
select *,SPLIT(col1,'\\|@\\|') as SplitString from testSplit
```

Result -

[image: Split function result]

Do let me know if this fulfills your requirement or not .

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> adf.withColumn("split_data",split($"data","\\|@\\|")).show(false)
+---------------+---------------+
|data           |split_data     |
+---------------+---------------+
|abc|@|pqr|@|xyz|[abc, pqr, xyz]|
|aaa|@|sss|@|sdf|[aaa, sss, sdf]|
+---------------+---------------+
```

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from split_data").show(false)
+---------------+
|data           |
+---------------+
|abc|@|pqr|@|xyz|
|aaa|@|sss|@|sdf|
+---------------+


scala> spark.sql("""select data,split('abc|@|pqr|@|xyz', '\\|\\@\\|') as split_data from split_data""").show(false)
+---------------+---------------+
|data           |split_data     |
+---------------+---------------+
|abc|@|pqr|@|xyz|[abc, pqr, xyz]|
|aaa|@|sss|@|sdf|[abc, pqr, xyz]|
+---------------+---------------+
```

Note: inside spark.sql function pass your select query between `""" """` & escape special symbols with `\\`.